# Excel - Minimum and If statement - date error

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula that checks the status and name to be ongoing and joe blogs (in this example), and once finding a match, will identify the oldest date of a ticket raised.

My formula currently includes:

```
=MIN(IF('Sheet2'!AA:AA="ONGOING",IF('Sheet2'!Q:Q="Joe Bloggs",'Sheet2'!B18:B49)))
```

I also tried:

```
=IF((AND(sheet2!$AA:$AA="ongoing", 'Sheet2'!$Q:$Q="Joe Bloggs")), MIN('Sheet2'!B18:B49),"No")
```

In Column B contains dates. Q contains names, AA contains the status.

At the moment when this runs I get the result '00/01/1990'. 
I have done some checks to find the error, and appears to be around the targets name, as when the second formula is tried, the output is "no". The name is definitely in the Q column, and I have completed other formulas including countifs which have worked perfectly fine.

I have done a lot of searching to find nested ifs and min statements to have no joy , would be grateful of any advice / tips. It may be a simple error to some.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. You have a brief explaination of your columns `B`, `Q`, and `AA` which are relevant to the formula you are working on, but it's not clear what that data looks like down the rows (perhaps some sample data of a few relevant rows for those three columns and what you would expect to see as a result of a functioning formula). Also, are these formulas entered as Array/CSE formulas, or just as-is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula works well on my data (as below). If I close the formula with ENTER only, I get the result '37128' and if I close the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER I get the expected result, '25/08/2001'.

---

**Edit:** *As @FocusWiz said in the comments, the only major difference (other than different column names) between my formula and yours is the the last range in your formula (B18:B49) is a different sized range to the other two, which are referring to full columns.*

*This could be solved either by using the same row range for all three column references (AA18:AA49, Q18:Q49, B18:B49) or referencing the full column range for all three ranges (AA:AA,Q:Q,B:B).

---

This is your formula I'm talking about:

```
=MIN(IF('Sheet2'!AA:AA="ONGOING",IF('Sheet2'!Q:Q="Joe Bloggs",'Sheet2'!B18:B49)))
```

And this is the formula in my workbook `F7`:

```
=MIN(IF(B:B="ONGOING",IF(A:A="Joe Bloggs",C:C)))
```

As you can see in the formula editor, squiggly brackets '{}' show around the formula when it has been closed as an array formula.

[image: Joe Bloggs]

If that doesn't work for you, please post some sample data with datatypes so we can help figure out what is causing the lookup value to miss the data.

Comment: I suspect the problem comes from the third part of the formula, where the OP is referencing 'Sheet2'!B18:B49 but both of the other parts are referencing the entire column.  While I am unsure what Excel does in that situation, it will not give the correct results.  If that column needs to be restricted, the formula probably should be:
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!AA18:AA49="ONGOING",IF(Sheet2!Q18:Q49="Joe Bloggs",Sheet2!B18:B49)) so that each range is equal.

Comment: @FocusWiz I can't believe I didn't notice that last range, D'oh! That definitely seems like the problem. I'll add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try entering this as an **array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF(sheet2!AA:AA="ongoing",IF(sheet2!q:q="Joe Bloggs",sheet2!B:B)))
```

FYI I found the solution [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-if-multiple-criteria).
You will have to apply a date format to the result.

Comment: I think you meant

=MIN(IF(Sheet2!AA:AA="ongoing",IF(Sheet2!Q:Q="Joe Bloggs",Sheet2!B:B)))

Answer (score 0):

While I like the technique offered by Patrick (I have frequently forgotten an "else" portion of a formula and gotten "false" as a value in a cell but never thought of a use for that...thank you!), I think this question highlights an issue we all can have with array formulas.  As girlvsdata indicates, your original formula:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!AA:AA="ONGOING",IF(Sheet2!Q:Q="Joe Bloggs",Sheet2!B:B)))
```

(modified above to be more generic for column B) will also work when entered as an array formula.

What likely happened is that somehow the formula got edited and was not re-entered as an array formula.

While I do not dislike array formulas, I do try to avoid them because I have fat fingers and will frequently mess them up by accidentally hitting the wrong key as I am modifying other cells.

Here is an alternative without using an array formula:

```
=INDEX(LARGE((Sheet2!Q:Q&Sheet2!AA:AA="Joe bloggs"&"ongoing")*(Sheet2!B:B),COUNTIFS(Sheet2!Q:Q,"Joe Bloggs",Sheet2!AA:AA,"ongoing")),1)
```

What it does is basically create a candidate date value for every row that has "joe bloggs" and "ongoing" which is equal to the date in column B for all such rows.   All other rows get a zero candidate date value.  The LARGE function takes the smallest nonzero date by counting the n valid candidates with the COUNTIFS function and taking the nth largest such candidate.